# What is the origin of the electric charge?

Tags: charge, field-theory, standard-model

What is the origin of the electric charge? In order to explain mass we had to postulate the existence of a quantum field (Higgs field), and we say that elementary particles get their mass by interacting with this field.

But where does electric charge come from? Is electric charge the result of particles interacting with some field or is it just a property of some fields (e.g. electron field)?

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4238/2451) Phys.Se post.

Comment: Also [What is charge actually? How to define it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106605/what-is-charge-actually-how-to-define-it)

Comment: Also [Why do we have an elementary charge but no elementary mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4238/why-do-we-have-an-elementary-charge-but-no-elementary-mass)