# What is the essence of electric charge?

Tags: charge

What is the essence of electric charge? Is it an independent object carried by the charged particles, or simply some kind of property of charged particles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is charge?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109535/) and links therein.

Comment: Other possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106605/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57199/2451